# How to do cross platform reCAPTCHA on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

How do I do cross-platform **reCAPTCHA** in **Xamarin Forms**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of creating your own captcha that I know about. The simple one doesn't require a server for verification. which is to show a number or an image and ask the user to recognize that image or text. The verification will happen locally so it's not dynamic but you can lock the system after several trials and apply a good RNG to limit the automation attacks.

The second type will require a web service to get the image or the random text from the server. When the user registers or log in or call the other service that you want to protect, send this value with it and validate it before processing the request to save traffic.